# How to add the i18n extension to jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2, gettext

According to [this document](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/extensions/), I wrote the following code

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment
from gettext import GNUTranslations

translation = GNUTranslations()
env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])
env.install_gettext_translations(translation)
name = input("Enter your name: ")
tm = Template("{% trans %} Hello {{ name }} {% endtrans %}")
msg = tm.render(name=name)
print(msg)
```

However, I get an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'trans'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because you instantiate à new Template() object. 
By default it doesn't use the Environment you previously defined but a temporary environment.
Have a look to the source code of the Jinja2 class Template() and you'll have more information.

What you need is something more like `template = env.get_template('index.html')` then `template.render(name=name)`